# i need help to get the input values to the respected variables

Tags: c#

I need help for getting the input from a text file and assign these values to the appropriate variables. i am beginner in c#. i got stuck on how to get these values. i want any one to fill the rest of the code in the while loop.
sample of text data would be like this
1 10 10 5 500
2 10 5 5  250
3 20 4 4  320

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadInputDetails
{
    class Boxdetails
    {
        private string boxno;
        private double length;
        private double height;
        private double depth;
        private double volume;


    // Declare a number of box of type string:
    public string boxno
    {
        get 
        {
           return boxno; 
        }
        set 
        {
           boxno = value; 
        }
    }

    // Declare  properties of box of type double:
    public double length
    {
        get 
        { 
           return length; 
        }
        set 
        { 
           length = value; 
        }
    }
    public double height
        {
            get
            {
                return height;
            }
            set
            {
                height = value;
            }
        }
    public double depth
        {
            get
            {
                return depth;
            }
            set
            {
                depth = value;
            }
        }
    public double volume
        {
            get
            {
                return volume;
            }
            set
            {
                volume = value;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/boxvalues.txt"))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post some sample data from `boxvalues.txt`

Comment: 1 10 10 5 500    2 10 5 5 250

Comment: the sample data posted here is on sperate lines or are they in one single line??

Comment: you can use String `Split()` method to separate values

Comment: 1 10 10 5 500 will be in a single line

Comment: can u just write a single line of code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing data in `boxvalues.txt` like this:

```
1 10 10 5 500
2 10 5 5 250
```

You can retrieve the values like:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] Parts=line.Split(' ');
    boxno=Parts[0];  //1
    length=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);  //10
    height=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);  //10
    depth=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);  //5
    volume=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);  //500
}
```

Read more about string splitting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: values of `height`, `length`, `depth` and `volume are in double. Kinldy use `Convert.ToDouble()` before assigning to respective variables